# Как разбить Git репозиторий на два независимых в github.com

Tags: git, github

Добрый день!
Собственно, сабж! Есть репозиторий, который содержит два `python`-пакета. Хотелось бы разбить на два независимых репозитория, чтобы история осталась у обоих...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение оказалось элементарным:
Создал в github'е новый репозиторий и сделал в нём pull от своего основного. Получилось два репозитория с одинаковым содержимым и оба с полной историей изменений! ))